issue with `AzureOpenAiChatOption` - missing `getTopK` method - application hangs
When I try to use spring-ai with Azure OpenAI, the application hangs. I suspect the initialisation of ChatOptions. I observe a RuntimeException from BeanWrapperImpl when the application tries to read data from getTopK, a method that does not exist in AzureOpenAiChatOption.
